# Как сделать поиск в бд из нескольких полей ввода

Tags: python, django

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        if 'search_filter' in request.GET:
            firstname = request.GET.get('firstname')
            lastname = request.GET.get('lastname')
            gender = request.GET.get('gender')
            age = request.GET.get('age')
            pologenie = request.GET.get('pologenie')
            sity = request.GET.get('sity')
            if gender == 'пол не выбран' and not age :
                print("err")
            user_list = Profile.objects.filter(Q(lastname__icontains=lastname) , Q(firstname__icontains=firstname))
        else:
            user_list = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
        subscribers_list = Subscribers.objects.filter(Q(ot_user_subscribers=request.user.profile) | Q(userss=request.user.profile))
        friends_list = Friends.objects.filter(users=request.user.profile)
        return render(request, 'board/search.html', {'user_list':user_list, 'friends_list':friends_list, 'subscribers_list':subscribers_list})
```

---

я в шаблоне могу передать имя фамилию город возраст статус пол как мне определять если какое-то поле вдруг не заполнено и в результате фильтровать без заполненного поля вдруг я не ввёл название города то отфильтровать по всем указанным фильтрам которые заполнил

```
        irstname = request.GET.get('firstname')
        lastname = request.GET.get('lastname')
        gender = request.GET.get('gender')
        age = request.GET.get('age')
        pologenie = request.GET.get('pologenie')
        sity = request.GET.get('sity') это я получаю из форма фильтра
```

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь добавить условие проверки для каждого поля ввода перед фильтрацией запроса:

```py
if gender == 'пол не выбран':
    gender = None
if age == '':
    age = None
if sity == '':
    sity = None

user_list = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)

if firstname:
    user_list = user_list.filter(firstname__icontains=firstname)
if lastname:
    user_list = user_list.filter(lastname__icontains=lastname)
if gender:
    user_list = user_list.filter(gender=gender)
if age:
    user_list = user_list.filter(age=age)
if pologenie:
    user_list = user_list.filter(pologenie=pologenie)
if sity:
    user_list = user_list.filter(sity__icontains=sity)
```

Это позволит тебе фильтровать только по заполненным полям ввода и искать пользователей по указанным параметрам.

Comment: Спасибо у меня теперь есть понимание как проверять много полей и при этом отфильтровать записи без кучу кода всё работает